# Moving image in video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I downloaded Blender today to try and edit videos. In the video I'm trying to edit I need to move a picture from one point to another in the time span from 0s to 7s plus 22frames (just an example, i need to move an image like 10 times within the whole video).

Is there a function for this? If so, how does it work?

My google searches only told me how to move the image in general and how to slide the image strip!

Answer (score 1):

Use Transform strip: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/video_editing/sequencer/strips/effects/transform.html

Or use the add-on which will allow to do the image animations directly in the preview: https://github.com/doakey3/VSE_Transform_Tools